# how to allow access to mic and video permission on FireFox v.99

Tags: firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am not able to click on the Allow button to access the camera/mic authentication popup in the Firefox browser using Selenium WebDriver with Java.

Below is the code which is used:

[image]